# Pseudo-elements and flexboxes in CSS

Tags: css, flexbox, pseudo-element

I am learning CSS and I am seeing something I don't understand. I am essentially doing the following:

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
}

div.flexbox::after {
  display: block;
  content: "X";
}

.item {
  flex: 1;
  height: 200px;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="item red"></div>
  <div class="item blue"></div>
  <div class="item green"></div>
</div>
```

I would have expected the "X" to appear on a new line, given that it is a block-level element. However, it is appearing inline -- at the end of the row of divs.

I am using firefox 52.7.4 for what it's worth.

Any insights would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/  *By default, flex items will all try to fit onto one line.*  float or display on flex children have no effects ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudo-elements don't exist outside the bounding boxes of the element they're appended after. If you inspect the element, you'll see the `::after` appear within the `<div class="flexbox">` element.

Answer (score 5):

You are using flexbox and the default behavior is [`nowrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap). Then you should specify any `width` or `flex-basis` that make the total width of the child elements exceed the width of their container in order to have the wrap.

`display:block` will have no effect in this case, you need to consider the flex properties to force the line break.

Here is an example:

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

div.flexbox::after {
  content: "X";
  flex-basis:100%;
}

.item {
  flex:1 0 30%;
  height: 200px;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="item red"></div>
  <div class="item blue"></div>
  <div class="item green"></div>
</div>
```